# How to split data into two new record in Unix?

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a data which is need to separate a record into two new record. My sample data is this:

```
id  country  place
 1   A       mall park
 2   B       beach
 3   C       hotel resort
 4   D       museum
 5   E       garden
```

I want the data to become like this:

```
id  country place
1    A      mall
1    A      park
2    B      beach
3    C      hotel 
3    C      resort
4    D      museum
5    E      garden
```

The data is tab delimited. I tried using `sed` and `awk`, but I can't get the correct syntax. Are there other command which I can use so that I can have my desired output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Pivot table in UNIX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747893/creating-pivot-table-in-unix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '
        FNR==1{                                 # Read first line
                max=NF                          # save no of fields
                print                           # print header
                next                            # go to next line
        }
  NF>max{                                       # if no of fields are greater than max fields
                split($0,fd)                    # split record by fields sep, and store in array fd
                NF=max-1                        # set NF to max-1 
                for(i=max; i in fd; i++)        # loop through fd from max
                       print $0,fd[i];          # print modified record, and field
                next                            # stop processing go to next
        }$1=$1                                  # $1=$1 is for making tab as o/p field separator for unmodified record 
   ' file
```

**Input**

```
$ cat f
id  country  place
 1   A       mall park
 2   B       beach
 3   C       hotel resort
 4   D       museum
 5   E       garden
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" 'FNR==1{max=NF; print; next}NF>max{split($0,fd); NF=max-1; for(i=max; i in fd; i++)print $0,fd[i]; next}$1=$1' f
id  country  place
1   A   mall
1   A   park
2   B   beach
3   C   hotel
3   C   resort
4   D   museum
5   E   garden
```

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to do with `awk`:

```
 awk -v OFS="\t" 'NF == 3 { print } NF == 4 { print $1, $2, $3; print $1, $2, $4 }' some_file
```

And not much more difficult with `sed`:

```
sed '/ /{h;s/ .*//p;x;s/[^\t]\+ //}' some_file
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

here set the OFS. output field seperator as tab.

```
echo "$line" | 
awk -v var="$mycol_new" -F $'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {$3 = var; print}'
```

**Metho2:**

or just set the field separator as \t.

```
... | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"}; {print $1}'
```

**Method 3:**

If you want to use awk, the way to supply the delimiter is either through the -F argument or as a FS= postfix:

```
awk -F '\t' '{ print $2 }' yourfile
```

Or:

```
awk '{ print $2 }' FS='\t' yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$ cat f
id |country| place
 1 | A  |    mall park
 2 | B  |    beach
 3 | C  |    hotel resort
 4 | D  |    museum
 5 | E  |    garden
$  awk -F'|' '{n=split($3,a," "); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {$3=a[i];print}}' f
id  country place
 1   A   mall
 1   A   park
 2   B   beach
 3   C   hotel
 3   C   resort
 4   D   museum
 5   E   garden
```

NOTE : You need to change the delimeter from pipe to tab.

Answer (score 0):

Short ***awk*** solution(spreading `place` column values into separate rows):

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NF>3 {for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$2,$i;next;}; {$1=$1; print}' file
```

The output:

```
id  country place
1   A   mall
1   A   park
2   B   beach
3   C   hotel
3   C   resort
4   D   museum
5   E   garden
```

---

`OFS='\t'` - output field separator, set to `\t`

`NF>3` - check if there's more than 3 fields(in case if `place` column contains more than one word)